# How to restart a standalone Adobe Air/Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

How can I get a standalone Adobe Air/Flex application to restart itself?

It doesn't work with the suggested solution on: http://www.colettas.org/?p=267.

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package
{
  import mx.core.Application;
  import mx.core.WindowedApplication;
  import adobe.utils.ProductManager;

  public function reboot():void
  {
    var app:WindowedApplication =
        WindowedApplication(Application.application);

    var mgr:ProductManager =
        new ProductManager("airappinstaller");

    mgr.launch("-launch " +
        app.nativeApplication.applicationID + " " +
        app.nativeApplication.publisherID);

    app.close();
  }
}
```

> Also make sure that the
>   “allowBrowserInvocation” option is
>   turned on in the AIR application
>   descriptor template

["How to restart an AIR application from code"](http://www.hufkens.net/2009/03/how-to-restart-an-air-application-from-code/)

Comment: fYI: This doesn't work in debug mode. Because the code you posted was exact the same as we used already. Now I tried it in an installed instance and it did work!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Hello dear i have been fixed this methode for Flex 4.6

```
package
{
    import adobe.utils.ProductManager;

    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
    import spark.components.WindowedApplication;

    public function Reboot():void
    {
        var app:WindowedApplication = WindowedApplication(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication);

        var mgr:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");
        mgr.launch("-launch "+app.nativeApplication.applicationID+" "+app.nativeApplication.publisherID);
        app.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Thanks for edit, VMAtm :) 
@rightPath you must read different version by mx and spark component frameworks :)

Thanks for improvement :)