# Restart/Reboot a android app with Adobe Air in Flash AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I searched for alternatives to restart my android application, but the only way I found to reboot is build ​​with [Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821749/how-to-restart-a-standalone-adobe-air-flex-application).

Can i restart my android adobe air app with as3 flash? How i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with anything built into Adobe AIR on mobile. The capabilities of AIR are extremely limited compared to native applications. You would have to build an AIR Native Extension (ANE) to handle it. Worth noting that I don't think this is possible at all on iOS (natively or otherwise), so if you are deploying to both you would need to account for this. This would likely also be the reason why you can't do it in AIR for Android, as AIR for mobile tends to appeal to the lowest common denominator. If one can't do it natively, it is likely Adobe didn't include it for the other.

See this question on how to do it natively:
[how to programmatically "restart" android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app)

Comment: The link in my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821749/how-to-restart-a-standalone-adobe-air-flex-application) show how to do in Flex... Is it wrong?

Comment: There is a large difference between AIR for desktop and AIR for mobile. What you want is not possible in AIR for mobile without writing and Native Extension, likely because it is not possible (at all) on iOS. So in that sense, yes it is wrong.

Comment: Really there, had not realized that the question of the link was about a Desktop application. Lost interest me to see it was not Flex and Flash. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: If someone else stumbles upon this with similar need, then you can try this. First let me warn you that this will not work if you are using ANEs. What you can do is create simple loader swf that is your document class. Which creates a worker, which then loads your app. If you want to "restart" then kill the worker thread running your app and create a new one.